# I can't extrude on the z axis

Tags: modeling, extrude

I was trying to extrude the edges in the z axis using the extrude tool from the toolbar and not the shortcut key. The first time I extruded the edges it was fine. But the second time I tried to extrude the edges I couldn't do it in the z axis. It was allowing me only in the x axis. I was wondering what have I done wrong.

[image]

Comment: I got the same problem, just fix it by appling all transforms.

Answer (score 2):

(Blender 2.92)
Wow. This is a curious one. I think this is what's going on..

[image]

You're extruding edges, along their median (actually mean) Normal, which is to say the mean normal of their vertices. In the first extrusion, all the vertex normals have a -Z component, the X's and Y's cancel, so the mean normal is -Z. In the second extrusion, none of the vertex normals has a Z component, the other components cancel, and so the Normal is 0. Blender seems to gives an arbitrary vector for this?

TL;DR

Fill the hole and  extrude a face, which *has* a normal, or use the XYZ setting for the tool.

The behaviour has changed in version 2.93

Comment: I don't see the problem. Maybe it's just incorrect use? I don't have to create a face.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks! This has been fixed in 293 .. I wonder how, though? .. i.e. how Blender decides what the mean normal of a collection of vertices is, when the vector sum is 0? I suspect it must be doing what this post suggests you do manually. Although, come to think of it, I don't know how blender defines the normal of an arbitrary ngon, either, reasonably economically. If I knew where to look.. :)

Comment: Oh yeah I see it changed, just tried it in 2.83.5, I've edited my answer to give a full explanation on how to work with the tool to achieve what he wants... still no need for a face, but you mention the XYZ setting already ;)  But I guess the answer that jmbenck gives is based on 2.93 and using it wrong - because in the old version, applying a transformation wouldn't help, he would still be facing the same problem that you explain in your answer: no Z component.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As @RobinBetts pointed out, the behaviour changed in Blender 2.93 (see below), so here's what to do if you have an earlier version:

If you simply want to constrain the extrude to the global Z axis (not some custom orientation), you can simply switch the *Extrude Region and Move* tool from using the *Normal* to the *XYZ* axis with the button at the top. Or if you keep the *Normal* option, just grab the circle instead of the Plus. This let's you extrude freely without constraining the direction. If you now hit <kbd>Z</kbd>, the direction gets constrained to the Z axis just like it does when you're moving, rotating or scaling things.

[image: extrude free]

And this is how it works in 2.93 and above: After the first extrude, you have the option to further *move* the extruded part by grabbing the arrow, or do another *extrude* by grabbing the plus.

First extrude:

[image: first extrusion]

Now if you want to move it further down without extrusion, use the arrow - if you hover over it, it becomes white:

[image: move]

But if you want to do another extrusion, hover your mouse over the Plus to grab it and it shows in white:

[image: second extrude]

Just pull it down like you did the first time and you have another extrusion:

[image: result]